# ¿Como simular la siguiente acción en React JS?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy intentando simular esta acción donde tengo dos Select Option y dos botones.
Uno para agregar un campo seleccionado del lado izquierdo al derecho, y el segundo regresar nueva mente el valor al primer Selec option.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tengo hasta ahora es lo siguiente. Dos arrays uno que representa una peque bd el cual llena de info el primer Select. Y el otro array representaría mi segundo select

```
articulos: [{
            codigo: 1,
            descripcion: 'papas',
        }, {
            codigo: 2,
            descripcion: 'naranjas',
        }, {
            codigo: 3,
            descripcion: 'peras',
        }],

        value: []
```

Lo que realizo es lo siguiente aquí estoy llenando mi primer select

```
<Input size="sm" type="select" name="selectMulti"
                            multiple={true} value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>

                            {this.state.articulos.map(item => (
                                <option value={item.codigo}>{item.descripcion}</option>
                            ))}
                        </Input>
```

Y aquí el segundo con el Array value[].

```
<Input size="sm" type="select" name="selectMulti1" id="exampleSelectMulti" multiple>
                            {this.state.value.map(item => (
                                <option>{item}</option>
                            ))}
                        </Input>
```

El problema que tengo hasta ahora es que en mi handleChange actualiza el estado del segundo array cada ves que selecciono uno y mas datos.

```
 handleChange(e) {
    var options = e.target.options;
    var value = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (options[i].selected) {
            value.push(options[i].value);
        }
    }
    this.setState({ value: value });
}
```

Mi pregunta es ¿Que podría implementar como un intermediario para cuando seleccione un dato de la lista y presione el boton agregar lo pase del otro lado?.

Comment: Hola, has intentado algo? Si es asi por favor edita y pon el codigo tambien.

Comment: @EugeniBejan Acabo de publicar mi código, gracias

Comment: hola Ricardo bienvenido a [es.so] porfavor no utilices el campo de respuesta para completar tu pregunta, simplemente dale click al boton de editar que se encuentra abajo de tu pregunta entre compartir y reportar o simplemente haz click en [edit]

Comment: @Federico Gracias por el consejo son las primeras interacciones con Stack Overflow  que tengo aun no entiendo muy bien como funciona pero gracias por la observación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes obtener el resultado deseado implementando dos componentes, el primero cuyo estado contenga los datos de dos Arrays que harán las veces de los datos de las dos cajas, y el elemento seleccionado en determinado momento, el segundo componente debe ser stateless y lo único que hará sera controlar la selección, con el fin de pasar su valor interno al componente padre.

Resultado final

[image: Estado inicial]

[image: Selección de elemento]

[image: Resultado final]

Código de componente padre

```js
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            arr1: [1,2,3,4,5], // Elementos de primera caja
            arr2: [], // Elementos de segunda caja
            selected: null // Elemento seleccionado
        }

        this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this)
        this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this)
        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this)
    }

    // Funcion encargada de actualizar elemento seleccionado
    handleSelect(selectedVal) {
        this.setState({
            selected: selectedVal !== this.state.selected ? selectedVal : null
        })
    }

    // Funcion encargada de pasar elementos del primer Array al segundo
    handleAdd() {
        if (this.state.arr1.includes(this.state.selected)) {
            this.setState({
                arr1: this.state.arr1.filter((val) => val !== this.state.selected).sort(),
                arr2: [...this.state.arr2, this.state.selected].sort(),
                selected: null
            })
        }
    }

    // Funcion encargada de pasar elementos del segundo Array al primero
    handleRemove() {
        if (this.state.arr2.includes(this.state.selected)) {
            this.setState({
                arr1: [...this.state.arr1, this.state.selected].sort(),
                arr2: this.state.arr2.filter((val) => val !== this.state.selected).sort(),
                selected: null
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        { 
                            this.state.arr1.map((val) => {
                                return <Item
                                        key={val}
                                        handleClick={this.handleSelect}
                                        value={val}
                                        selected={this.state.selected === val} /> 
                            })
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.handleAdd}>Agregar</button>
                    <button onClick={this.handleRemove}>Remover</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        { 
                            this.state.arr2.map((val) => {
                                return <Item
                                        key={val}
                                        handleClick={this.handleSelect}
                                        value={val}
                                        selected={this.state.selected === val} /> 
                            })
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }
}
```

Código de componente stateless

```js
class Item extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.props.handleClick(this.props.value)
    }

    render() {
        return <li className={this.props.selected ? 'selected' : ''} onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.value}</li>
    }
}
```

Y aquí te dejo el código CSS que use

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
    display: flex;
}

div:nth-child(1),
div:nth-child(3) {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    width: 100px;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

button {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    padding: 7.5px 15px;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: dodgerblue;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2.5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

li.selected {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias si funciono.